# How to estimate the maximum force which a human can apply in tug-o-war?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, everyday-life, estimation

I'm interested in the maximum force which a human can apply to an object by pulling it with a rope (assuming a very good standing on the ground). A natural limit seems to be his weight but in the different situation of doing a pull-up, he is able to apply more force.

How could I get a an estimate for this?

Answer (score 1):

The maximum force which can be applied to a rope in a tug-o-war is equal to whichever of these three things is the smallest; the strength of the puller (it is not unusual for a strong person to be able to pull more more than his weight), his traction with the ground, and the resistance offered by the other side.

The winning side in a tug-o-war is actually the side with the most traction with the ground.  The force on the rope is always equal for both sides, in accordance with Newton's third law.

Answer (score 0):

A human has been able to apply a pull force of 400N but the average a person could apply is a bit less- 315N